# Building for x86 and x64 platform with CMake with Xcode and Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xcode4, cmake

I started using CMake pretty recently.
It is a really easy script language but there are many tricks to learn and tutorials on the cmake website is not much help.

Basically I want to build my project for

- Windows (using visual studio 2010) x86 and x64
- Mac os (using Xcode 4) x86 and x64

Dependending on the OS and plateforme I want to link certain libraries.

I figured out for Windows that I can use WIN32 or WIN64 to set this up.
But I can't find the equivalence for mac os.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: *"Windows (using visual studio 2010) x86 and x64"* - Clang can be used for Windows VS toolchain, too. See [Getting Started with the LLVM System using Microsoft Visual Studio](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the "if(APPLE)" and other variables that Tobias pointed you to in his answer, you can also inspect what generator you're using to make decisions on a per-generator basis if necessary.

```
if(CMAKE_GENERATOR MATCHES "Xcode")
  ...
elseif(CMAKE_GENERATOR MATCHES "Win64")
  ...
endif()
```

On the Mac, you can build universal binaries by setting the target property OSX_ARCHITECTURES, or the variable CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES: http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt:OSX_ARCHITECTURES

Alternatively, you can build two single-architecture binaries using two separate build trees with a single value in CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES for each build tree.

On Windows, you should simply have two separate build trees, on for your 32-bit build and one for your 64-bit build.

Comment: I got the point on windows, I came to discover that WIN64 does not the trick, so I used CMAKE_CL_64. However I must say that I didn't get what you were saying for mac os. I will dig into it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
if (APPLE)
....
endif(APPLE)
```

more information:
http://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#System_.26_Compiler_Information

Comment: Do you know if APPLE32 and APPLE64 exist ?

Comment: The OSX_ARCHITECTURES variables turns out to be sufficient for my purpose. Thanks